# Send push notifications by limit per user

Tags: 7, notifications

I have configured multiple rules to send push notifications to multiple users with no limit (because [push notifications](https://www.drupal.org/project/push_notifications) does not provide any limit how much notifications system send to user). I would like send push notification to particular user with limit of 4 notification for some extent of time. If user get lot more notification he remove app from mobile or frustrate. Anybody have any idea how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to add a user field. This field will keep track of the number of push notifications sent and will increment every time you send a new push notification to the user.

In your rule, add a condition that checks the value of the field and execute the actions if value <= 4. 
Then, in the action part of the rule, increment the value of the field by one.

Comment: user field in which way you are talking about?

Comment: admin/config/people/accounts/fields

Comment: But also need to set time limit where within one hour 4 push notifications would be sent. Over it can send after one hour or two hours per user / token.

Comment: You can set a cron job or a rules scheduler to reset the value of the field to 0 every X hours